# How to use the value defined before the callback, even if the value changes during the async operation?

Tags: javascript

I tried to isolate the problem as much as from my original code. The following outputs "2" to the console:

```js
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = [];
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        this.listeners.push(callback);
    }

    fireEvent() {
        let me = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            me.listeners.forEach(callback => {
                callback();
            });
        }, 100);
    }
}


let observable = new Observable();

let x = 1;

observable.on("event", () => {
    console.log(x);
})

observable.fireEvent();

x = 2;
```

What I really wanted to do was to make callback print "1" (the value before the x is changed by another piece of code). So after a long debugging session I did something like this:

```js
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = [];
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        this.listeners.push(callback);
    }

    fireEvent() {
        let me = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            me.listeners.forEach(callback => {
                callback();
            });
        }, 100);
    }
}


let observable = new Observable();

let x = 1;

var unboundFunction = () => {
    console.log(this);
};

var boundFunction = unboundFunction.bind(x);

observable.on("event", boundFunction);

observable.fireEvent();

x = 2;
```

For reasons I don't understand second code prints the Window object in Chrome console, but the similar code works as I want in my project. I am guessing because there was no "this" before in the original code, but "this" refers to the "window" in chrome so it works differently when run in console.

Is this the right way to do what I want?

Comment: "*Is this the right way to do what I want?*" I don't see a reason to play around with `this` and binding, just use `() => {let y = x; console.log(y)}` as a callback and you'd get a copy of `x` at the time the callback was defined. If you really want to use `bind`, then `console.log.bind(null, x)` but it's just a bit ugly to my taste.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to create a local block-scoped constant that gets assigned the current value of `x`:

```js
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = [];
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        this.listeners.push(callback);
    }

    fireEvent() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.listeners.forEach(callback => callback());
        }, 100);
    }
}


let observable = new Observable();

let x = 1;
{
  const innerX = x;
  observable.on("event", () => {
      console.log(innerX);
  });
}

observable.fireEvent();

x = 2;
```

> For reasons I don't understand second code prints the Window object in Chrome console

Because the `unboundFunction` is an arrow function defined on the top level, `this` will always refer to either the global object, or to `undefined` in strict mode.

If it refers to something else in your project, the `unboundFunction` must not be declared on the top level. `.bind`ing an arrow function doesn't change its `this`.